# Python: Finding Regex occurance for variable char

Tags: python, regex, string, character

I know, for example, that if I want to find lengths of all the occurrences of consecutive 'a's

in input = "1111aaaaa11111aaaaaaa111aaa", I can do

```
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'a+', input)]
```

However, I'm not sure how to do this with a char variable. For instance,

```
CHAR = 'a'
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'??????', input)]    # Trying to find occurrences of CHARs..
```

Is there a way to do this??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're asking for is:

```
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'{}+'.format(CHAR), input)]
```

Except of course that this won't work if `CHAR` is a special value, like `\`. If that's an issue:

```
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'{}+'.format(re.escape(CHAR)), input)]
```

---

If you want to match two or more instead of one or more, the syntax for that is `{2,}`. As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) say:

> `{m,n}` Causes the resulting RE to match from m to n repetitions of the preceding RE, attempting to match as many repetitions as possible. For example, `a{3,5}` will match from 3 to 5 `'a'` characters. Omitting *m* specifies a lower bound of zero, and omitting *n* specifies an infinite upper bound. As an example, `a{4,}b` will match `aaaab` or a thousand `'a'` characters followed by a `b`, but not `aaab`…

That gets a little ugly when we're using `{}` for string formatting, so let's switch to `%`-formatting:

```
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'%s{2,}' % (re.escape(CHAR),), input)]
```

… or just simple concatenation:

```
[len(s) for s in re.findall(re.escape(CHAR) + r'{2,}', input)]
```

Comment: THanks!! Sorry, one more question: from your Regex findall, how to detect more than 2 consecutive characters?   I thought r'{}1+' will work, but it doesnt :(

Comment: Why did you think `1+` would work? That gives you, e.g, `a1+`, which is an `a` followed by one or more `1`. Let me edit the answer to explain how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a general solution that should work for strings of any length:

```
CHAR = 'a'
[len(s) for s in re.findall(r'(?:{})+'.format(re.escape(CHAR)), input)]
```

Or an alternative using `itertools` (single character only):

```
import itertools
[sum(1 for _ in g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(input) if k == CHAR]
```

Comment: If you're going the itertools route, it seems a shame to make each group into a list. Just write a trivial `ilen` function, or use the one from `more-itertools`, or inline it as `sum(1 for _ in g)`.

Comment: @abarnert yeah that is a good point, edited with your suggestion to avoid the temp list.